# What does/might the name Schroedinger mean?

Tags: meaning, person-names

A quick Google yielded no fruit; perhaps a language aficionado or expert could shed some more light.

Comment: Are you asking who it refers to or what words the surname evolved from?

Comment: I think it’s supposed to be in the same vein as a question here about ‘Fahrenheit’ — that is, ‘what would it have meant if it had been an actual german word?’

Comment: When referring to the physicist, it's "Schrödinger" or "Schroedinger", but under no circumstances "Schrodinger".

Comment: Welcome. There were/are a herd of Schrödingers out there, just like there are Wallaces for instances. What does the name Wallace mean ? Voting to close.

Comment: It's a question about onomastics. What details are needed?

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, but according to Wiktionary, *Schröder* comes from the Low German *schroden* = "to cut". But I do tend to agree that the question is off-topic. If the name is a word in the modern language then you can look it up in a dictionary. Otherwise, as a_donda points out, knowing English doesn't tell you where there name "Wallace" comes from.

Comment: @RDBury stackexchanges are about expert knowledge, not just knowing the language and thus being able to answer the question; this is a trap that language sites easily fall into, like ELL. Expert knowledge (or just google-fu) can tell us that ‘Wallace’ comes from the Anglo-Norman-French ‘Waleis’, meaning ‘Welshman’, and way back to Old Low Franconian ‘Walhisk’, meaning foreigner.

Comment: Guys, I didn't mean Schrödinger and Wallace have an ethymological kinship, just Schrödingers without any context can mean a lot of people, the reknown physicist included, just like Wallace can mean a lot of people, a reknown naturalist included. stackexchange=expert knowledge ? .k ... if you say so :-) *duckandaway*

Comment: @a_donda: The "expert knowledge" remark was related to the interpretation that assumes the question asks what a name like "Schrödinger" (or in your example, "Wallace") means in terms of the actual current or former words it was originally derived from - which would probably be on-topic, and indeed require expert knowledge rather than just basic knowledge of the language. For this interpretation of the question, it is completely irrelevant which person named Schrödinger is meant, or who they were, just that the name "Schrödinger" is or was actually in use as a real name.

Comment: In the  current shape, the question asks in present tense, what the name means, and it means nothing, except that the name of the parents or husband/wife is/was "Schroedinger". Ancient, etymological meanings require the past tense and need to be formulated accordingly.

Comment: @DJG Since some apparently got your intention wrong, here's a recommendation to avoid re-closing: rephrase the question to *Where does the name* Schrödinger *come from and what did it mean originally?*

Comment: @userunknown: the close-reopen-cycle has already been gone through. Yes, the question is badly written, but, as David Vogt wrote, it's still obvious what it is about. If somebody asks what a name means, they're asking about onomastics, that really goes without saying. What you commented here and under my answer (as well as your downvote if it was yours) is just ill-humored nitpicking.

Comment: @HalvarF: If you value the question that much, why don't you improve it?

Comment: @userunknown I wrote an answer that should have made it clear how I understood the question. I'm not comfortable with substantially editing a question that I myself have answered, as this shouldn't be a platform for self-talk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names ending on -er often refer to the person's origin (cf. "Ich bin ein Berliner"), and -ing or -ingen are typical endings of village or town names. So some ancestor could have been a *Schrödinger* in the sense of coming from *Schröding* or *Schrödingen*. There may have been several places of that name. As an example though, the [wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6ding_(Kirchberg)) of a very old village named *Schröding* in Bavaria states that its name goes back to a man named *Scort* who lived around 800, and it was referred to as *Scrotingin* in a document from 1050. Place names on -ing or -ingen often go back to person names, so *Scrotingin* or *Schröding(en)* would mean something like "where Scort and his folks live". "Schröder" is also a common (much younger) family name that goes back to old words for taylor or drayman.

Of course, when refering to family name *Schrödinger*, these are all just speculations, common patterns that don't need to apply to this specific family. See also [Wortherkunft.de](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/Schr%C3%B6dinger/), although they don't cite any sources either.

*Erwin Schrödinger* was an Austrian physicist, most known for his important contributions to quantum theory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger

A popular meme is Schrödinger's cat, a thought experiment (1935) where a cat is in a superposed state of being both alive and dead at the same time if you use quantum mechanics to describe it. This paradox is still relevant when discussing the philosophy of quantum mechanics. Also, a fundamental equation in quantum mechanics is named after Schrödinger.

Comment: Good answer. Let me add, that in Austria (where Erwin Schrödinger was born) the name *Schrödinger* sounds like the name of a person from Germany. *Schrödinger* is not a typical Austrian name, same is true for *Schröder.* I don't know where Erwin Schrödinger's early ancestors came from, but I would guess, that it's Germany. Erwins Father [Rudolf Schrödinger](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Schrödinger) also was born in Vienna/Austria and Erwins Grandfather Joseph Schrödinger was in Vienna when he studied Chemistry, but I didn't find out where Joseph was born.

Comment: People don’t generally use ‘meme’ in the general sense of ‘an idea that spreads’. Unless you did mean to suggest that Schrödinger’s cat is a meme in its other, more common, sense, something funny that lots of people know, which I guess is true :D

Comment: @Fivesideddice: I mean it in the sense of a story that is much more widely known than other comparable ideas of physics thanks to a number of special properties (cat, death, understandability, paradox) that make it more rewarding to tell. I read Dawkins, but I don't follow meme theory, so I might not be current on what people understand by it.

Comment: Müller, Maier, Wagner, Fischer, Schuster, ... are very common names, ending in "er" and are, to my knowledge, not based on origin, but on profession: operating a (corn) mill, processing milk, building trolleys, ... .

Comment: @userunknown: I think we are all aware of that. What are you trying to tell me? What profession is Schrödinger then in your opinion?

Comment: Du meinst der Name kann nur die Profession oder die Herkunft bedeuten? Und ist Dir nicht aufgefallen, dass Du zirkulär argumentierst, dass der Ort den Namen von der Person hat, die dort lebte? Was war nun zuerst da, Schrödingers Katze oder das Ei aus dem sie schlüpfte?

Comment: @userunknown Wo holst du denn das jetzt her? Soll ich die die Antwort nochmal erklären? Der Name ist vermutlich aus der Herkunft eines Vorfahren aus einem Ort entstanden. Dieser Ort hat auch einen Namen, der selbst wiederum auf eine Person zurückgeht. Diese Person hat ihrerseits einen Namen, die zum Beispiel auf einen Beruf zurückgehen könnte. Vier Zeitebenen in einer Antwort. Und all das ist nur Spekulation, es kann auch jemand aus völlig anderen Gründen irgendwann   "Schrödinger" genannt worden sein. Aber das sind typische Muster, wie solche Namen über mehrere Ebenen zustande kommen.